# MineSweeper with GUI, How to change the size of the field and then refresh the JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jdialog

I am trying to make a minesweeper game with GUI and when I am adding a menu where people can change the size of the field and number of mines, I wasn't be able to change JFrame. I want to change the number of buttons and mines if player enters something to the JTextBox and presses the submit button which are on a JDialog. Basically I want to change sizeX, sizeY, mines variables at the *MineSweeper* class and then refresh the frame with new values.

```
    public class MineSweeper {
private static int sizeX=20;
private static int sizeY=20;
private static int mines=20;

private static JFrame frame;

public static void setX(int x){
    sizeX = x;
}
public static void setY(int y){
    sizeY = y;
}
public static void setM(int m){
    mines = m;
}
public static void refreshFrame(){
    frame.validate();
    frame.repaint();
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    frame = new JFrame("");
    frame.setTitle("MineSweeper Game");
    frame.setBackground(Color.white);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu options = new JMenu("Options");
    JMenuItem gameProperties = new JMenuItem("Game Properties");
    menuHandler menuHandling = new menuHandler();
    gameProperties.addActionListener(menuHandling);
    options.add(gameProperties);
    menu.add(options);
    frame.setJMenuBar(menu);
    frame.setSize(sizeX*sizeY, sizeX*sizeY);
    if(gameProperties.isEnabled()) frame.validate();
    frame.add(new MineSweeperGUI(sizeX, sizeY, mines));
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

```
class menuHandler implements ActionListener{
JDialog dialog;
JButton button;
JPanel panel;
JLabel sizeRow, sizeCols, mineCount;
JTextField sizeX, sizeY, mines;
int  x, y, m;
public menuHandler(){
    dialog = new JDialog();
    dialog.setSize(400,120);
    panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 2));
    sizeRow = new JLabel("Row size of the field: ");
    sizeCols = new JLabel("Column size of the field: ");
    mineCount = new JLabel("Number of mines: ");
    sizeX = new JTextField(10);
    sizeY = new JTextField(10);
    mines = new JTextField(10);
    panel.add(sizeRow);
    panel.add(sizeX);
    panel.add(sizeCols);
    panel.add(sizeY);
    panel.add(mineCount);
    panel.add(mines);
    button = new JButton("Submit");
    panel.add(button);
    dialog.add(panel);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    dialog.setVisible(true);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String sizeofRows = sizeX.getText();
            String sizeofCols = sizeY.getText();
            String countofMines = mines.getText();
            MineSweeper.setX(Integer.parseInt(sizeofRows));
            MineSweeper.setY(Integer.parseInt(sizeofCols));
            MineSweeper.setM(Integer.parseInt(countofMines));
            MineSweeper.refreshFrame();
            dialog.dispose();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Unrelated: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to adopt the approach used in this simple [game](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons). It uses a `JPanel` named `buttonPanel` that has a `GridLayout` of `JToggleButton` instances. When the user changes the size of the game, an `ActionListener` invokes `resetGame()`, which does

```
buttonPanel.validate();
```